# Quick way to check if your processor has virtual machine extensions?

Tags: virtualization, multi-platform

I work for a tech shop and we inherit computers from various places.  I am looking for a small program/script I can run to tell me if the processor has any virtual machine extensions built into it.  I am looking for something along the lines of [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) where it is a small simple dedicated program.  A Linux or Windows program would work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this on a Linux box:

```
# egrep --color -i "svm|vmx" /proc/cpuinfo
```

VMX is the Intel processor flag and SVM is the AMD flag. If you get a match then you have support.

Comment: Heres a doc page describing /proc/cpuinfo flags: http://blog.incase.de/index.php/cpu-feature-flags-and-their-meanings/

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, just cat /proc/cpuinfo and look at the "flags" section of the output.

For Windows, SecurAble seems to be the best option as far as I can tell, although someone else may have a better suggestion.

Comment: Via this: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/05/easy-way-to-determine-if-cpu-supports-windows-7-virtual-pc-xp-mode/

SecurAble doesn't even require installation.

Comment: Here's a direct link http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Answer (score 1):

For Windows CPUZ is a very quick way. It will list under the "Instructions" section on the first page.

http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php

Answer (score -2):

Alternative on Windows
Install Cygwin -> Open Cygwin terminal -> Run /cat/procinfo